# Selenium printing error The selected printer could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, firefox

This is in reference to the solution provided by @lifeiscomplex [How to handle Firefox print dialog box in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68788695/how-to-handle-firefox-print-dialog-box-in-selenium)

The code is:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import FirefoxProfile
driver_path = 'geckodriver.exe'
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

profile_options = FirefoxProfile()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11.5; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
profile_options.set_preference('profile_options = FirefoxProfile()', user_agent)
profile_options.set_preference("print_printer", "Mozilla Save to PDF")
profile_options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
profile_options.set_preference("print.show_print_progress", True)
profile_options.set_preference('print.save_as_pdf.links.enabled', True)
profile_options.set_preference("print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)

# set your own file path
profile_options.set_preference('print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file.print_to_filename',
                               "testprint.pdf")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path, options=firefox_options,
                           firefox_profile=profile_options)


URL = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/'


driver.get(URL)
search_field_id = 'yfin-usr-qry'

element_search_field = driver.find_element_by_id(search_field_id)
element_search_field.clear()
element_search_field.send_keys('TSLA')
element_search_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.execute_script("window.print()")
sleep(20)
driver.quit()
```

When i run this code, the code executes itself does not produce any error but i get this error dialogbox in firefox. Even if you press Ctrl+P you will get the same dialog box:
[image]

However if manually clicked on print from `application menu` in FireFox during the page loading process i do get the print dialog:
[image]

Could you please advise why am i getting that dialogbox.

I did change the toggle to True before running the script, which shouldn't matter since since its already in `profile_options.set_preference("print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)`:
[image]

**Edit**:

I was able to get the print dialog box to start reappearing by commenting out this line:

```
profile_options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
```

But i am not able to find the file `testpage.pdf` which is suppose to be generated.

---

```
My system information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows
OS:          10
Python:      3.8.8
Selenium:    3.141.0
Firefox:     90.0.2
Geckodriver: 0.29.0

----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you provide your system information like I did in my previous answer?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Is this your current code?  I'm asking, because you mentioned in the other question that you changed something and I don't see that change reflected.

Comment: I have not made any change in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments of this question ["How to handle Firefox print dialog box in Selenium"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68788695/how-to-handle-firefox-print-dialog-box-in-selenium) you mentioned that you had changed this line from my answer:

```
profile_options.set_preference('print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file.print_to_filename', "testprint.pdf")
```

to this:

```
profile_options.set_preference('print.printer_Microsoft_Print_to_PDF.print_to_filename', "testprint.pdf")
```

If you want to change that line you would have to change at least one more in the code you posted.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import FirefoxProfile
driver_path = 'geckodriver.exe'
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

profile_options = FirefoxProfile()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11.5; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
profile_options.set_preference('profile_options = FirefoxProfile()', user_agent)

# this line was changed
profile_options.set_preference("print_printer", "Microsoft Print to PDF")

profile_options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
profile_options.set_preference("print.show_print_progress", True)
profile_options.set_preference('print.save_as_pdf.links.enabled', True)

# this line was changed
profile_options.set_preference("print.printer_Microsoft_Print_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)

# this line was changed
profile_options.set_preference('print.printer_Microsoft_Print_to_PDF.print_to_filename', "testprint.pdf")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path, options=firefox_options,
                           firefox_profile=profile_options)


URL = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/'


driver.get(URL)
search_field_id = 'yfin-usr-qry'

element_search_field = driver.find_element_by_id(search_field_id)
element_search_field.clear()
element_search_field.send_keys('TSLA')
element_search_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.execute_script("window.print()")
sleep(20)
driver.quit()
```

There might be another line that needs to be changed, but I cannot test the code above to verify this, because I'm using macOS and not Windows 10.

You also mentioned that you commented this line out:

```
profile_options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
```

commenting out this line will launch the `print dialog` as showed in  the graphic below.

[image]

Comment: If i do so in silent mode such as suggested by you: profile_options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True) I get the error `The selected printer could not be found`

Comment: I changed another line in the code that I posted to this question.  Please run it as is and tell me what happens.

Comment: Thanks, the code is working great! I got a `testpage.pdf` generated with the pdf print. Its amazing that you were able do this for PC with a mac. Amazing!!!

Comment: I'm happy that it's working for you.  I have written a lot of `selenium` code and I have found that most of it can be reused on other platforms with a few modifications.   I write `selenium` code for all the browsers (e.g., chrome, mozilla and edge).