# How do I make `print_printer` work in Python Firefox Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

## Problem

### Not Working Code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
    download(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/", 0)


def download(url, n):
    # Set the path to the Firefox WebDriver executable with the exe in the path
    driver_path = "D:/PROGRAMMING/Website-to-PDF/FirefoxDriver/geckodriver.exe"
    download_path = "./Downloads"
    output_pdf = f"Download {n}.pdf"
    
    firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
    firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    
    # Start printing the page without needing to press "print"
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.show_print_progress", False)
    firefox_options.set_preference('print.save_as_pdf.links.enabled', True)

    # Get rid of the headers
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.print_headerleft", "")
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.print_headerright", "")
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.print_footerleft", "")
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.print_footerright", "")

    # Using print_printer
    firefox_options.set_preference("print_printer", "Mozilla Save to PDF")
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)
    firefox_options.set_preference('print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_filename', f"{download_path}/{output_pdf}")

    gecko_service = webdriver.FirefoxService(executable_path=driver_path, port=4444)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, service=gecko_service)

    print(f"Downloading File {n}")
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.execute_script('window.print();')
    time.sleep(15)
    driver.quit()
    print(f"Finished Download.\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I do not get a file downloaded any where on my computer. I also don't get the option of where to save the file at all.

### Working Code but Extra Steps Needed

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
    download(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/", 0)


def download(url, n):
    # Set the path to the Firefox WebDriver executable with the exe in the path
    driver_path = "D:/PROGRAMMING/Website-to-PDF/FirefoxDriver/geckodriver.exe"
    download_path = "./Downloads"
    output_pdf = f"Download {n}.pdf"
    
    firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
    firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    
    # Start printing the page without needing to press "print"
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.show_print_progress", False)
    firefox_options.set_preference('print.save_as_pdf.links.enabled', True)

    # Get rid of the headers
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.print_headerleft", "")
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.print_headerright", "")
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.print_footerleft", "")
    firefox_options.set_preference("print.print_footerright", "")

    # Using print_printer
    # firefox_options.set_preference("print_printer", "Mozilla Save to PDF")
    # firefox_options.set_preference("print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)
    # firefox_options.set_preference('print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_filename', f"{download_path}/{output_pdf}")

    gecko_service = webdriver.FirefoxService(executable_path=driver_path, port=4444)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, service=gecko_service)

    print(f"Downloading File {n}")
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.execute_script('window.print();')
    time.sleep(15)
    driver.quit()
    print(f"Finished Download.\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see here, with the print_printer commented out, my code works but it prompts me where I want to save the file and what the filename should be.

[Save Print Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHWdP.png)

I want it to automatically save in my `download_path` with filename `output_pdf`.

### What I've Tried

I have tried changing `/` to `\` & `\\` but it still won't work.

I have tried using a similar method done in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68834871/21486622) where I added a `user_agent` with my own, set the preference for it, but `profile_options = FirefoxProfile()` will not work because `webdriver.Firefox(options=profile_options)` will not work as the `options` parameter needs to have an instance of `options.Options`.

I also tried other libraries such as `pyautogui` which worked but gave inconsistent results; I tried `pdfkit` and `wkhtmltox` but it gave me errors that I also couldn't find a solution to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Logging

I did some logging on the geckodriver by adding the following line

```
gecko_service = webdriver.FirefoxService(executable_path=driver_path, port=4444, log_output='gecko.log')
```

From there, I saw that a line in the log:

```
JavaScript error: , line 0: NS_ERROR_GFX_PRINTER_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

From here, I changed my `print_printer` lines to:

```
profile.set_preference("print_printer", "Microsoft Print to PDF")
profile.set_preference("print.printer_Microsoft_Print_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)
profile.set_preference('print.printer_Microsoft_Print_to_PDF.print_to_filename', output_path)
```

### Adding Profile and Options Correctly

Also, if you noticed, I changed from `firefox_options` to `profile` because in `selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options`, you can specify your own `.profile` attribute.

Here are the changes:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference(...)
...

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument(...)
...

firefox_options.profile = profile

# This line remained the same
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, service=gecko_service)
```

From this, I also saw that the only argument that did not give any errors for me was `--headless`.