# Printing a PDF with Selenium Chrome Driver in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I have no problems printing without headless mode, however once I enable headless mode, it just refuses to print a PDF. I'm currently working on an app with a GUI, so I'd rather not have the Selenium webdriver visible to the end user if possible.

For this project I'm using an older version of Selenium, 4.2.0. That coupled with Python 3.9.

```
import os
from os.path import exists
import json
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

# Paths
dir_path = os.getcwd()
download_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "letters")
chrome_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "chromium\\app\\Chrome-bin\\chrome.exe")
user_data_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "sessions")

website = "https://www.google.com/"


def main():
    print_settings = {
        "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2,
        "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False,
        "isLandscapeEnabled": True
    }

    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = chrome_path
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={user_data_path}")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--enable-print-browser')
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(print_settings),
        "savefile.default_directory": download_path,  # Change default directory for downloads
        "download.default_directory": download_path,  # Change default directory for downloads
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,  # To auto download the file
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    })
    options.add_argument("--kiosk-printing")

    driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get(website)
    driver.execute_script("window.print();")

    if exists(os.path.join(user_data_path, "Google.pdf")):
        print("YAY!")
    else:
        print(":(")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else coming across this with a similar issue, I fixed it by using the print method described here: [Selenium print PDF in A4 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164550/selenium-print-pdf-in-a4-format)

Using my example from above, I replaced:

```
driver.execute_script("window.print();")
```

with:

```
pdf_data = driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.printToPDF", print_settings)
with open('Google.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(base64.b64decode(pdf_data['data']))
```

And that worked just fine for me.

Comment: "print_settings" don't work anymore. Use this settings instead: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/939ac7f/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions